# Get request parameter map in Customiz map?

Tags: java, collections

I want my request parameter map in my custom map like

```
Map<String, String> reqMap =(HashMap<String, String>)request.getParameterMap();
```

Above statement gives me following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap
```

Can any one guide me how can I get all request parameters in my custom map?
Don't want to write for loop to get parameters one by one which cause me performance issue.

Comment: Is HashMap a custom version you wrote? Why?

Comment: It's not custom version. It's java's only. Just want request parameters in my new map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> reqMap = request.getParameterMap();
CustomMap<String, String> customMap = new CustomMap<String,String>();
customMap.putAll(reqMap);
```

Of course, you may need to iterate through the map elements in your `putAll()` implementation. Otherwise it is not possible.

**UPDATE:**
Just saw your comment, Thai is easy then,

```
Map<String, String> reqMap = request.getParameterMap();
Map<String, String> newMap= new HashMap<String,String>();
newMap.putAll(reqMap);
```

or, you can even pass the `reqMap` as a constructor argument to `new HashMap<String, String>(reqMap);`

Comment: Thanks. This solves my above exception. Basically I am sending this map at business layer. So I can't send request object. But while retrieving that map at Business layer This map shows me object of Collections$UnmodifiableMap<k,v> from which I want to retrieve my all parametrs. Plz suggest me

Comment: You need to pass the `newMap` to your business layer, not `reqMap`. You can not do any operations on `UnmodifiableMap` except iterating through it. In my answer we have created a map (`newMap`) which is **not** an `UnmodifiableMap`.

Comment: How to get only specified parameters, eg: `http://localhost:8080/project/?pid=1&cid=20&start=1&end=24&uid=9`. If I want to get only pid and cid, how can I get only this attributes using `getParameterMap()`

Comment: did you try `getParameterMap().get("pid")` etc. Or you even can get directly with `request.getParameter("pid")` or request.getAttribute("pid")`.

Answer (score 4):

Beware of casting the Map to `String, String` as `request.getParameterMap()` returns a Map of type `String, String[]` since Java 6.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, String> returnMapOfRequest(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        try 
        {
            Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
            Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
            while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) 
            {
                String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
                Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaders(headerName);
                while(headers.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    String headerValue = headers.nextElement();
                    map.put(headerName, headerValue);
                }
            }
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames();
            while(e.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String key = (String) e.nextElement();
                map.put(key, session.getAttribute(key));
            }
            while(parameterNames.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
                String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
                for(int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) 
                {
                    String paramValue = paramValues[i];
                    map.put(paramName, paramValue);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Exception in returnMapOfRequest  ::  ", e);
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
Map<String, String> reqMap =(HashMap<String, String>)request.getParameterMap();
```

To:

```
Map<String, String> reqMap =(Map<String, String>)request.getParameterMap();
```